# Getting bad map relo error while trying to attach an eBPF program to tc

Tags: linux, networking, maps, ebpf

When trying to run the command,

```
sudo tc filter add dev veth0 egress bpf direct-action obj a.o sec classifier
```

I'm getting this error,

```
libbpf: prog 'pdm_main': bad map relo against '.rodata.str1.1' in section '.rodata.str1.1'
ERROR: opening BPF object file failed
Unable to load program
```

The sections in my object file,

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 classifier    00000638  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  2 .maps         00000020  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000678  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  3 .rodata.str1.1 0000002c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000698  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .rodata.str1.16 00000036  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000006d0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 license       00000004  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000706  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  6 .debug_loclists 00000105  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000070a  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  7 .debug_abbrev 000001c9  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000080f  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  8 .debug_info   0000080f  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000009d8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  9 .debug_str_offsets 000002a4  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000011e7  2**0
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 10 .debug_str    000006ec  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000148b  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 11 .debug_addr   00000030  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001b77  2**0
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 12 .BTF          00001037  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001ba8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY
 13 .BTF.ext      00000470  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00002be0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY
 14 .eh_frame     00000030  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00003050  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
 15 .debug_line   00000220  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00003080  2**0
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 16 .debug_line_str 000000f8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000032a0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
```

How to fix this? When i don't use eBPF map in my code it doesn't give the same error.

Comment: It looks like libbpf is getting confused about some string literals. In normal programs, string literals are loaded as a heap section, but since eBPF has no heap that is an issue. This often happens when using bpf_trace_printk or similar helpers. It is recommended to use the [printk macros of libbpf](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/bpf_helpers.h#L287) since they will store the string in a different way to avoid the generation of a .str.rodata section.

Comment: Yeah now the program works after I removed all the string literals from the program. Thanks for the help!